# How to send admin generated content in emails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, ruby-on-rails-4

So, I have quite a simple application - how it works is you visit the site there's an dropdown select menu and email input field and a submit button.

The idea is you choose what type of food your interested in in the dropdown select, you then enter your email and you can receive email updates either hourly, daily, or weekly.

The issue I'm having is how do I connect the admin content from the admin panel to the emails so that the person who enters there email gets an array of content from that category either hourly, daily, or weekly?

Thanks in advanced!

Comment: hmmm this question is really quite broad. just generally saying you want to "connect the admin content to the emails"... covers a million different possible ways of solving this problem. You need more than just a little bit of information here, and you probably need to start by googling email in rails... and then deciding how you actually want the end-result to work. (exactly what goes into what emails how often? what content is dynamic? what static?). Then look at the tutorials you googled for to see how you can build up email templates and use dynamic content in them...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look on this rails cast: [Sending HTML email](http://railscasts.com/episodes/312-sending-html-email)

Only thing you should do is redefine `def weekly` and `weekly.html.erb` template.

Or you can go another way and use [maktoub gem](https://github.com/Sandglaz/maktoub)

Comment: Thanks! Ryan Bates video is super helpful for email! However, how do I dynamically update the emails? So there's a content model and admins add different content to different categories. I'd like each email that's sent to display a different piece of content related to that catefory.

Comment: I think in `def weekly` you should write something like `@content = ModelName.content` and in template `<% @content.each do |x| %> <%= render 'path/to/partial', content: x %>` and in this partial define formatting for each piece.